# UK Citizenship in 3 years possible by 10 Million Investor Tier 1 route?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, citizenship

I have plans of applying for the Tier 1 Investor visa UK. I am going to make significant investments amounting to no less than 10M GBP. This makes me eligible to apply for ILR after 2 years.

For those who don't know, the investor can:

- apply to settle after 2 years if you invest £10 million
- apply to settle after 3 years if you invest £5 million
- apply to settle after 5 years if you invest £2 million

I qualify for ILR after 2 years of my investment and Tier 1 Visa.

Does this mean that I can apply for citizenship after 3 years (that is 12 months after receiving ILR) of receiving Tier 1 Visa?

There is a requirement that the applicant must be in the UK exactly 5 years before the date of application of citizenship, but I am afraid I do not fit here as I am not working for a company on Tier 2 work visa since 5 years (the traditional immigration route), instead I am on the fastest route to ILR hence I could become eligible for ILR after 2 years. So I will definitely not be in the UK exactly 5 years before the date of application.

What do you think? Can I get British citizenship after 3 years since my Tier 1 visa and my investments in the UK begin? All UK Gov. documents assume that the citizenship applicant must have been in the UK for at least 5 years (as is the case for the majority of the times) but does this rule apply for fast-track route applicants who have invested more than 5M or 10M GBP? Notice that the Investor who invests 2M or more falls in the category of "ILR after 5 years" so there's no problem for them as well, just these 2 categories fall in a different situation.

Or is it the case that British citizenship can be applied for, in all cases including the 5 M and 10 M investment cases, only after 5 years in the UK with no absences of more than 450 days in those 5 years? This implies that investors who receive ILR after 2 and 3 years, respectively, have to wait for 3 and 2 years before they can apply for citizenship.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to satisfy the 5-year residency requirement in order to apply for British citizenship, regardless of how quickly you obtain Indefinite Leave to Remain.

> This implies that investors who receive ILR after 2 and 3 years, respectively, have to wait for 3 and 2 years before they can apply for citizenship.

That is correct based on my understanding of the existing legislation and Home Office guidance.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! I am of the same opinion. Since you have stated that this is based on your understanding of the existing legislation, I will wait some time for others to express their knowledge about this. If all agree about this opinion, I will mark this as "Accepted answer".